next-auth/react OAuthSignin error when signing in with ZITADEL
I am trying to sign in Next.js with ZITADEL but I take error when I try to sign in. I used this docs: https://zitadel.com/docs/examples/login/nextjs
I created project and application (UA) in ZITADEL UI.
I used this button code for rotate to sign in screen. And It is rotating to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthSignin url directly.
<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    onClick={() => signIn('zitadel', { callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/profile' })}
>
    Sign in with Zitadel
</Button>

Error screenshot
Actually I didn't understand the error. I need help for solution.
api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import ZitadelProvider from 'next-auth/providers/zitadel';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    ZitadelProvider({
      issuer: process.env.ZITADEL_ISSUER,
      clientId: process.env.ZITADEL_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.ZITADEL_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: `openid email profile offline_access`,
        },
      },
      async profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          firstName: profile.given_name,
          lastName: profile.family_name,
          email: profile.email,
          loginName: profile.preferred_username,
          image: profile.picture,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      token.user ??= user;
      token.accessToken ??= account?.access_token;
      token.refreshToken ??= account?.refresh_token;
      token.expiresAt ??= (account?.expires_at ?? 0) * 1000;
      token.error = undefined;

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.expiresAt) {
        return token;
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session({ session, token: { user, error: tokenError } }) {
      session.user = {
        id: user?.id,
        email: user?.email,
        image: user?.image,
        name: user?.name,
        loginName: user?.loginName,
      };

      session.clientId = process.env.ZITADEL_CLIENT_ID;
      session.error = tokenError;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

.env
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
ZITADEL_CLIENT_ID=291144798537056260
ZITADEL_CLIENT_SECRET=nTOaE3Hev1Td0tdZH0U54902jiQXiRpT
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=nTOaE3Hev1Td0tdZH0U54902jiQXiRpt
ZITADEL_ISSUER=https://localhost:8080

next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    experimental: {
        esmExternals: false,
        jsconfigPaths: true
    },
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        });

        return config;
    },
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: process.env.ZITADEL_ISSUER.slice(8),
                pathname: '/assets/v1/**',
            },
        ],
    },
}

I need help for connection. What is the problem? And How can I solve it?
